# How to concatenate value to set of strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's assume I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
REFERENCE_CODE   DUMMY_DATA
dog              foo
cat              fi
fish             fo
bird             fum
1                u
2                v
3                x
4                y
```

My goal is to create a dataframe that turns into:

```
REFERENCE_CODE  DUMMY_DATA
dog             foo
cat             fi
fish            fo
bird            fum
dog_1           u
dog_2           v
dog_3           x
dog_4           y
cat_1           u
cat_2           v
cat_3           x 
cat_4           y
fish_1          u
fish_2          v
fish_3          x
fish_4          y
bird_1          u
bird_2          v
bird_3          x
bird_4          y
```

I am able to get to:

```
REFERENCE_CODE  DUMMY_DATA
dog             foo
cat             fi
fish            fo
bird            fum
bird_1          u
bird_2          v
bird_3          x
bird_4          y
```

By using the following code:

```
df.REFERENCE_CODE = df.REFERENCE_CODE.fillna('')
df['REFERENCE_CODE'] = df['REFERENCE_CODE'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
headers = (df.REFERENCE_CODE != '') & ~df['REFERENCE_CODE'].fillna('').str.isnumeric()
res = df.groupby(headers.cumsum())['REFERENCE_CODE'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] + '_' + x)
df.REFERENCE_CODE.update(res[df.REFERENCE_CODE.str.isnumeric()])
```

How can I get it to apply to all the other ones and extend the dataframe, while not losing integrity of other columns..

Answer (score 0):

Idea is use cross join with filtered non numeric `REFERENCE_CODE` column with filtered rows with numeric values:

```
#simplify code
df['REFERENCE_CODE'] = df.REFERENCE_CODE.fillna('').astype(str)
mask = (df.REFERENCE_CODE != '') & ~df['REFERENCE_CODE'].str.isnumeric()

#filter by condition for matched and not matched rows
df1 = df[mask]
df2 = df[~mask]

#cross join
df = df1[['REFERENCE_CODE']].assign(A=1).merge(df2.assign(A=1), on='A')
#join columns together
df['REFERENCE_CODE'] = df['REFERENCE_CODE_x'] + '_' + df['REFERENCE_CODE_y']

#concat new DataFrame with first filtered
df = pd.concat([df1, df[['REFERENCE_CODE','DUMMY_DATA']]], ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
print (df)
   REFERENCE_CODE DUMMY_DATA
0             dog        foo
1             cat         fi
2            fish         fo
3            bird        fum
4           dog_1          u
5           dog_2          v
6           dog_3          x
7           dog_4          y
8           cat_1          u
9           cat_2          v
10          cat_3          x
11          cat_4          y
12         fish_1          u
13         fish_2          v
14         fish_3          x
15         fish_4          y
16         bird_1          u
17         bird_2          v
18         bird_3          x
19         bird_4          y
```